# Is it possible to consume a nuget package developed in .net 4.5 in .net core 1.1?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Is it possible to consume a nuget package developed in .net 4.5 in .net core 1.1 project?

I tried looking in multiple blogs but the solutions they provided are not working.

If it is possible to add the package and use the methods in dll can someone please help me on how to do it?

What changes I need to make in project.json?

Comment: You don't show how it failed, so I can only assume you don't even know much about what is .NET Core and its 1.1 release. If you are not in a hurry to learn this platform, wait for .NET Core 2.0 with proper tooling (project.json is dead). If you insist to try, edit your project.json so this console app targets .NET Framework runtime and then you can use that NuGet package.

Answer (score 3):

The *real* solution here is to take the existing project and compile it targeting *some flavor of* .net core (there are various targets, such as the various net-standards) - which will usually mean changing *some* (usually small) amount of the code. Without doing that, even if you got it to reference and compile, it would only work against .net 4.5, and at that point you might as well change your *consuming* project to target .net 4.5.